# Arch linux in Docker on a free system is running out of space

Tags: arch-linux, docker

I am building an `archlinux:base` image in Docker For Mac on a completely empty Mac filesystem (no spaces issues).

Printing a `df -h` early in the Dockerfile while building, shows this:

```
#6 [ 3/34] RUN df -h
#6 sha256:813a64bb126c8e765889bb10075a6c5acdcb4e734b83bf8737a8ddb927e987bd
#6 0.227 Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
#6 0.227 overlay          59G  5.3G   51G  10% /
#6 0.227 tmpfs            64M     0   64M   0% /dev
#6 0.227 shm              64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
#6 0.227 /dev/vda1        59G  5.3G   51G  10% /etc/resolv.conf
#6 0.227 tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
#6 0.227 tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /proc/acpi
#6 0.227 tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/firmware
#6 DONE 0.3s
```

In the next command, I do a pacman -Syyu, which updates packages. During this, I get this:

```
#7 28.09 downloading fish-3.1.2-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst...
#7 28.86 checking keyring...
#7 29.01 checking package integrity...
#7 30.57 loading package files...
#7 30.65 checking for file conflicts...
#7 30.66 checking available disk space...
#7 30.71 error: Partition /etc/resolv.conf is mounted read only
#7 30.71 error: Partition /etc/hosts is mounted read only
#7 30.71 error: not enough free disk space
#7 30.71 error: failed to commit transaction (not enough free disk space)
#7 30.73 Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
#7 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pacman -Syyu sudo fish --noconfirm]: exit code: 1
```

However, I do not see any space issues. Is it possible related to `tmpfs`?

Answer (score 1):

I actually think the last error there is kind of a red herring

I think this is the issue: https://github.com/moby/buildkit/issues/1267

Also referenced here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63652551/docker-build-vs-docker-run-dont-behave-the-same